# Error while trying to install Astropy 4.3 'ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe''

Tags: python, setuptools, versioning, dependency-management, astropy

I'm working on a project for uni which uses natural language search to acces data in virtual observatories. For this we thought that the OpenAI API (which uses GPT-3.5) could give us Astropy based code that we could retrieve and execute programatically. The problem is that the OpenAI API has knowledge up untill sept 2021, which means it can only work with Astropy 4.3. I've tried to downgrade my installation or reinstall it with this version, but it throws the following error:

```
'ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe'
```

I thought there was a possible solution in this [github issue](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/13255), so I did the following

- Downloaded the zip file of the 4.3.x version of Astropy
- Edited the `pyproject.toml` file to lock the markupsafe version
- Installed it using `pip install astropy-4.3.x.zip`, having the zip file at the same level as my `env` folder

But i got the following error:

`LookupError: setuptools-scm was unable to detect version for C:\users\my-user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-h5m59wap.`

And for that, i have not been able to find a working solution.
Another aproach that i tried was using pipenv, but it could resolve the dependency issue.

I hope someone might be able to help!

[P.S.] If you think there's a better way to use the OpenAI API and the Astropy and PyVO package, feel free to suggest!

Comment: What version of Python are you using?